# Why we can't get list of Object?

Tags: java, generics

I'm wondering why this code couldn't be compiled:

```
private static List<? super String> x() {
      return null;
}


List<Object> l = x();
```

List is of type object so we can store everything in it. Who can explain?

Comment: read about PECS (Producer extends and Consumer super)

Comment: A `List<? super String>` is allowed to be a `List<String>`, but you can't write `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Object> != List<? super String>
```

You can store everything on it.

```
l.add("a");
l.add(1);
l.add(new Object());
```

But you cannot assign a `List<? super String>` to a `List<Object>` because they aren't the same thing.

You can add a `BigDecimal` to a `List<Object>`, but you cannot add a `BigDecimal` to a `List<? super String>`.